# Reference a website in bib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I want to reference a website in my bib file. I use:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

I found:

```
@misc{Xmisc,
 %author    = "",
 %title     = "",
 %howpublished = "",
 %year     = "XXXX",
 %month    = "",
 %note     = "",
}
```

but this does not include **Last Visited** field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should consider changing to [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), and using its `urldate` field.

Comment: But I need `Harvard Style` references. Can I do that using biblatex ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant information isn't the package `natbib`. It is import which `bibliographystyle` do you use.

The `bibliographystyle` `plainnat` allows the following entries:

```
address    author    booktitle    chapter    doi    eid    edition
editor    howpublished    institution    isbn    issn
journal    key    month    note    number    organization
pages    publisher    school    series    title    type
url    volume    year
```

So you can do the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@misc{test,
author={Christian Faulhammer},
title={What is a minimal working example?},
howpublished ={Website},
year={2009},
month=8,
url ={http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html},
note ={last checked: 05.09.2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

With  biblatex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@online{test,
author="Christian Faulhammer",
title="What is a minimal working example?",
howpublished ="Website",
date = "2009-08-18",
url ="http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html",
urldate="2011-09-06",
}
\end{filecontents}
%\bibliography{references}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: @salamis: No problem. But think about the changing to `biblatex`. If you want to change please open a new question.

Comment: But I need Harvard style referencing. Is that possible with biblatex?

Comment: @salamis: The `biblatex` style `authoryear` based on the Harvard style.

Comment: @salamis: I edited my post.

Comment: With `biblatex`, use `\addbibresource{references.bib}` instead of `\bibliography{references}`.

Comment: @lockstep: I changed it.

Comment: What will this produce? And how will this be presented in the document? I need [author, year] in the document like natbib.

Answer (score 1):

Staying with BibTeX and `natbib` (and `har2nat`, if you're employing 'harvard'-style citation commands but wish to use the `natbib` package), you can always use the "note" field of the `@misc` entry type to record something like

```
note = "Last visited on dd/mm/yyyy",
```

Most bibliography styles I'm familiar with are programmed to print out the contents of the note field whenever the entry type is `@misc`.